# Explorer.exe in infinite crash loop caused by Taskbar.View.dll

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, crash, windows-11, windows-insider

My Windows 11 (build 25252.1000, pro for workstations insider preview) has a critical problem now that explorer.exe repeatedly crashes and restart almost every second. The problem occurs after installing a update stack package.

Event viewer crash log:

> Faulting application name: explorer.exe, version: 10.0.25252.1000, time stamp: 0x789ae93c
> Faulting module name: Taskbar.View.dll, version: 2022.32200.0.0, time stamp: 0x6376d1b5
> Exception code: 0xc0000409
> Fault offset: 0x0000000000316b93
> Faulting process id: 0x0x308
> Faulting application start time: 0x0x1D90A9F587B0F24
> Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SystemApps\MicrosoftWindows.Client.40887771_cw5n1h2txyewy\Taskbar.View.dll
> Report Id: e2b38f2e-c86c-44c4-9f07-f866dc7c2d51
> Faulting package full name:
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

Things I've tried:

- restart in safe mode. problem still.
- SFC and DISM commands. no help.
- replace the file with Taskbar.View.dll extracted from windows setup iso. still crashes but now it says the reason is about Windows.UI.Xaml.dll (I changed it back then)
- create a new user account. still crash. so the problem has nothing to do with my user profile.

I could not do a repair install because I am using the newest insider build so the ISO downloaded from ms site has a lower version than my system.

Any solution or idea? (I don't want to do a clean install. I have so many data and programs.)

Comment: If you cannot match a repair ISO to your current version (that can happen), then clean install is really your only other option.

Comment: “update stack package” - never heard of such a thing care to clear by editing your question

Comment: “ Any solution or idea? ” - [Download an ISO for the build your using](https://uupdump.net/), make sure you try a minimal boot, before you take such drastic measures

Comment: I was getting stack package updates after most insider updates. Not so much now, but they did not (do not) cause this issue

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue after installing (10.0.22623.1037) (KB5021304), uninstalling the update sorted my issue.